# how to write a update query for asp.net using session variables?

Tags: asp.net, sql, session, visual-studio-2012

Newbie alert!
I am currently working on a asp.net project on visual studio without having any previous experience or knowledge with it. I need to write a query which updates according to a where clause which includes a session variable.

I have a Session["patid"] which stores an integer value. The query part in my code goes like:

```
SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("update prescription set Medicine#1='"+med1txt.Text+"' where Patient_ID = Session["patid"]",con);
```

where con is a SqlConnection. With this I get quite a few build errors such as "; expected","Invalid expression term ')'", etc. Also Patient_ID is a int type attribute, so I can't use Session["patid"].ToString().
Could anyone suggest a solution to this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
String query = @"update prescription set medicine#1=@medicine where patient_id=@patientId";
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn)){
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@medicine", med1txt.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@patientId", Session["patid"]);
conn.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works perfectly and also from Massimiliano's reply I know it's much neater,easier and a better practice to use parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you are breaking all the best practices/security rules for doing this look at the below:

```
SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("update prescription set Medicine ='" + med1txt.Text + "' where Patient_ID =" + Session["patid"]",con);
```

I would use at least a SqlCommand with parameters to avoid SQL Injection,etc.

Please have a look [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter) for more info